# Pitch detection - count notes

Tags: javascript, pitch-detection

I'm using an autocorrelation algorithm to perform pitch detection on monophonic sounds (humming, whistling) and I get results good enough for what I'm attempting to do.
But If I whistle a melody with the notes **G F# D#** and log the result I get this sequence:

2x F# 
 3x G 
14x F# 
   **54x** G 
14x G# 
2x D  
  **52x** F# 
6x G
 14x F# 
3x G 
2x G   
 **28x** D# 
2x D 
33x D# 
4x D
 16x D# 
2x E 
2x D 
2x D#

We can see that the right notes are recognized and they are the ones with more repetitions, how can I know when it´s a real note or just a transition? Is there any kind of filter that I can apply to that array and get only the real notes G F# and D#?

I'm using this javascript code: https://github.com/cwilso/pitchdetect to perform the pitch detection and I'm wondering if there's some post process algorithm that I can apply to my results to filter the notes or if I have to increase the window on the autocorrelation algorithm.

In that thread on Signal Processing (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/how-to-get-the-melody-from-a-signal) the accepted answer mention something like a simple post processing applying a mode filter on my result sequence of pitches. What would be this mode filter?

Comment: It looks like you need to hone your whistling skills.

Comment: What language are you programming in?  Can you give us a code sample that demonstrates the problem? Please add these details to your question

Comment: @TonyK it appear that even perfect sine waves have these pitch variations.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I hope the informations added to the question help to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A mode filter is where you see which notes occur the most and discard the rest.   e.g. if you were to do a simple mode filter and discard anything with a value let than 20 then you would get 54x G, 52x F#, 28x D#, 33x D#   However you would have to calculate the mode value to use as it would depend on the tempo of the notes.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thanks, I was thinking of something like that, but I thought that would have a more accurate algorithm, something like checking the pitch variation and based on a threshold find when it's a new note. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mode filter is where you see which notes occur the most and discard the rest. e.g. if you were to do a simple mode filter and discard anything with a value less than 20 then you would get 54x G, 52x F#, 28x D#, 33x D#

However you would have to calculate the mode value to use as it would depend on the tempo of the notes.